# Solr autocomplete function with numbers

Tags: apache, search, indexing, solr, autocomplete

I am currently working with apache solr and I implemented an autocomplete function for a search text field. It works pretty well with letters, but the problem I have now is with numbers. Numbers will not be autocomplete, despite there are in my index. Does anyone know this kind of problem?

Heres my schema.xml:

```
    <fieldType name="suggest_de" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
                <analyzer type="index">
                    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
                    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
                    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                            splitOnCaseChange="0" splitOnNumerics="0"
                            generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="0"
                            catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" preserveOriginal="1"/>
                    <filter class="de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.ysolr.synonyms.HybrisSynonymFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="de" coreName="${solr.core.name}"/>
                    <filter class="de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.ysolr.stopwords.HybrisStopWordsFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" lang="de" coreName="${solr.core.name}"/>
                    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="solr/embedded/conf/stopwords_de.txt" ignoreCase="true" />
                    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
                    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
                </analyzer>
                <analyzer type="query">
                    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
                    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
                </analyzer>
            </fieldType>

<field name="autosuggest" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
        <field name="autosuggest_de" type="suggest_de" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />

        <copyField source="autosuggest" dest="autosuggest_de" />
```

and my solrconfig.xml:

```
<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
            <str name="mm">100%</str>
        </lst>
        <arr name="components">
            <str>suggest</str>
        </arr>
    </requestHandler>

<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
        <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">autosuggest</str>
        <lst name="spellchecker">
            <str name="name">default</str>
            <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
            <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookup</str>
            <str name="field">autosuggest_de</str>
            <str name="buildOnOptimize">true</str>
            <str name="accuracy">0.35</str>
            <str name="characterEncoding">UTF-8</str>
        </lst>
        <lst name="spellchecker">
            <str name="name">de</str>
            <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
            <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookup</str>
            <str name="field">autosuggest_de</str>
            <str name="buildOnOptimize">true</str>
            <str name="accuracy">0.35</str>
            <str name="characterEncoding">UTF-8</str>
        </lst>
    </searchComponent>
```

As I said there are no problems with letters, but everything starting with numbers is not returned in queries.

Comment: Can you check if numbers are present in stopwords_de.txt mentioned in ```<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="solr/embedded/conf/stopwords_de.txt" ignoreCase="true" />
                    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />```

Comment: No, there are no numbers in stopwords_de.txt. Just some plural words changed to singular as StemmingFilters for German are useless.

Comment: I cannot see anything else wrong here. I see that you are also using de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.ysolr.stopwords.HybrisStopWordsFilterFactory   , Can you see what kind of stopwords it is using?

Comment: Also in the file from HybrisStopWordsFilterFactory, there are no numbers in it. It has the same behavior as StopFilterFactory except for a different data source.

Comment: Additional information: In my solrfacetsearch I have 2 fields: autosuggest (article numbers) and autosuggest_de (other localized strings). Autosuggest is copied into autosuggest_de. When I send my query starting with numbers nothing is returned ( q=%22110%22&qt=%2Fsuggest&spellcheck.dictionary=de ). Does anyone know why numbers are not returned?